# How can I fix a non-properly loading custom Adapter when the item is out of screen

Tags: android, gridview, android-view, baseadapter

I'm building a view with a custom `ButtonAdapter`, which loads a `StringArray` and puts out a `GridView` with Buttons.
Until the buttons are out of the Screen everything loads fine, but the last few Buttons which I only can see when I scroll down, are wrong.

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, null);

            Button button = (Button) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setText(mobileValues[position]);
            Log.d("tag1", "value: " + mobileValues[position] +" position: "+ position);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
                    String mobile = b.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("tag1", "button: " + mobile);
                    if (mobile.equals("Bäm 1")){
                        play(R.raw.bam1);
                    } else if (mobile.equals("Buz")){
                        play(R.raw.buz);
                    } else if (mobile.equals("Bäm 2")){
                        play(R.raw.bam2);
                    } else if (mobile.equals("Wir nehmen das Geld")){
                        play(R.raw.gold2);
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Currently I'm passing in a string array with 26 Items. When it comes to the 20th button to draw, the `position` drops to `0` and the Button displays a wrong Text.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not setting the test for the views outside the screen. The correct code should be something like this

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;
    private View.OnClickListener onClListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
            String mobile = b.getText().toString();
            Log.d("tag1", "button: " + mobile);
            if (mobile.equals("Bäm 1")){
                play(R.raw.bam1);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Buz")){
                play(R.raw.buz);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Bäm 2")){
                play(R.raw.bam2);
            } else if (mobile.equals("Wir nehmen das Geld")){
                play(R.raw.gold2);
            }
        }
    };

    public ButtonAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, parent, false);
        }
        Button button = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText(mobileValues[position]);
        button.setOnClickListener(onClListener);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues != null ? mobileValues.length : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mobileValues[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```